# Simple OpenNI getUserPixels

Tags: java, kinect, processing, simple-openni

I'm new to Image Processing. How can I track multiple users, using getUserPixels() from Simple OpenNI for Processing? What does this take as parameters? How would I set up this code?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to keep track of detected users.

The `sceneImage()/sceneMap()` functions are handy to keep track of user pixels, but I also prefer enabling the `SKEL_PROFILE_NONE` profile for tracking users.

This works with the `onNewUser` and `onLostUser` events which return an integer: the id of that user. This id is important to keep track total users or the most recent user detected.
Once you have the user's id you can plug that into other SimpleOpenNI functionalities, like `getCoM()` which returns the user's "centre of mass"(the x,y,z position of it's body centre).

So, you would use the above mentioned user events to update an internal list of users:

```
import SimpleOpenNI.*;

SimpleOpenNI context;
ArrayList<Integer> users = new ArrayList<Integer>();//a list to keep track of users

PVector pos = new PVector();//the position of the current user will be stored here

void setup(){
  size(640,480);
  context = new SimpleOpenNI(this);
  context.enableDepth();
  context.enableScene();
  context.enableUser(SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_PROFILE_NONE);//enable basic user features like centre of mass(CoM)
}
void draw(){
  context.update();
  image(context.sceneImage(),0,0);
  if(users.size() > 0){//if there are any users
    for(int user : users){//for each user
      context.getCoM(user,pos);//get the xyz pozition
      text("user " + user + " is at: " + ((int)pos.x+","+(int)pos.y+","+(int)pos.z+",")+"\n",mouseX,mouseY);//and draw it on screen
    }
  }
}
void onNewUser(int userId){
  println("detected" + userId);
  users.add(userId);//a new user was detected add the id to the list
}
void onLostUser(int userId){
  println("lost: " + userId);
  //not 100% sure if users.remove(userId) will remove the element with value userId or the element at index userId
  users.remove((Integer)userId);//user was lost, remove the id from the list
}
```

HTH